# Is this a troff file, and if so how do I convert to ps or pdf?

Tags: linux, pdf, postscript, groff

I have a file with the following heading:

```
.PS
.ps 8.5

boxht = 1/6
boxwid = 0.3

moveht = 1/12
movewid = 0.15

linethick = 0
```

It looks like a `troff` file, at least that's what Linux `file` tells me (I have not been able to simply open it with, say, Evince). However, if I simply `groff -Tps somefile > somefile.ps`, it simply gives me the text of the file: it does not create the ps file following the code in it.

The question is, how do I convert this type of file into `ps` or `pdf`?

Comment: Incidentally, you should be able to view the file with `man ./file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to tell groff which set of macros to use in formatting the document.  For example, man-pages use the "an" macros, with the command-line option "-man".

To see what macros would apply, you have to look at more than just the slice that you have quoted.  xterm for instance has a file (ctlseqs.ms) which is formatted using the "s" ("-ms") macros.

The "-Tps" option may be redundant; most groff configurations appear to default to PostScript output.

Comment: Thanks. I ran `grog` and it told me `groff -t file` Anyway, accepted.

Comment: I had forgotten about grog - though it is simplistic, basically starting with all possibilities and discarding ones that do not fit.  For ctlseqls.ms, it offers all: "groff -t -man -ms ctlseqs.ms"